# Ansible win_update issue - A malformed block was encountered while loading tasks

Tags: ansible

I tried using either of the below windows update playbooks and got the same error when I execute it.

```
---
- name: Install all windows security and critical updates and wait 10 mins
  hosts: windowsservers
  tasks:
    win_updates:
      category_names:
        - CriticalUpdates
        - SecurityUpdates
      blacklist:
        - Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows
      reboot: yes
      reboot_timeout: 600
```

```
---
- name: Install all windows security and critical updates and wait 10 mins
  hosts: windowsservers
  tasks:
    win_updates:
      category_names:
        - CriticalUpdates
        - SecurityUpdates
      blacklist:
        - Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows
    reboot: yes
    reboot_timeout: 600
```

Below is the error message I'm getting when I tried executing either of the above playbooks. I've been searching everywhere but couldn't find any related issue. Can someone, expert in Ansible, please help?

```
ERROR! A malformed block was encountered while loading tasks: {u'win_updates': {u'blacklist': [u'Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows'], u'reboot_timeout': 600, u'category_names': [u'CriticalUpdates', u'SecurityUpdates'], u'reboot': True}} should be a list or None but is <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleMapping'>

The error appears to be in '/home/username/ansible/playbooks/windowsupdate/install_windows_secupdate.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Install all windows security and critical updates and wait 10 mins
  ^ here
```

Below is what I'm using as a reference article.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_updates_module.html
https://www.ansible.com/blog/windows-updates-and-ansible

Answer (score 2):

As clearly explained by your error message

> ERROR! A **malformed block** was encountered while loading **tasks**: {u'win_updates': {u'blacklist': [u'Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows'], u'reboot_timeout': 600, u'category_names': [u'CriticalUpdates', u'SecurityUpdates'], u'reboot': True}} **should be a list** or None but is <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleMapping'>

`ansible-playbook` is expecting a list in the `tasks` parameter of your play inside your playbook (you usually have several tasks in your play).

This error is preventing either of your playbook version to actually execute further.

Regarding your second playbook version (besides the list/hash format error), your `reboot*` params are not indented correctly: they are `win_updates` module options, not task level options (e.g. `loop`, `register`, `when`,...). The first version is the good one.

This is a fixed version of your playbook (syntax only, not tested) where:

- I transformed `tasks` to a list
- I added a name to your task as a general good practice

```yaml
---
- name: Install all windows security and critical updates and wait 10 mins
  hosts: windowsservers
  tasks:
    - name: Install updates
      win_updates:
        category_names:
          - CriticalUpdates
          - SecurityUpdates
        blacklist:
          - Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows
        reboot: yes
        reboot_timeout: 600
```

Verifying the syntax:

With your above playbook:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook_bad.yml --syntax-check
ERROR! A malformed block was encountered while loading tasks: {'name': 'Install updates', 'win_updates': {'category_names': ['CriticalUpdates', 'SecurityUpdates'], 'blacklist': ['Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows'], 'reboot': True, 'reboot_timeout': 600}} should be a list or None but is <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleMapping'>

The error appears to be in '/tmp/playbook_bad.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Install all windows security and critical updates and wait 10 mins
  ^ here
```

With the proposed fix:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml --syntax-check
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: windowsservers


playbook: playbook.yml
```

The warning is just because I do not have your machine/group in my inventory.

Comment: No, this doesn't work either. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: No: you did not paste the code correctly or you would not get the same error.

Comment: Just edited to add the result of the syntax check. As you can see, the error is gone with my fixed version.